# SonarQube static analysis for angular2 project fails on Unable to load component class ProjectReactor

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have an angular 2 app I want to try out sonar on. I followed the instructions step-by-step.

After running the following command:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=abcdef -Dsonar.sources=./src/**/*.ts -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.organization=lacikigor-github -Dsonar.login=abcdef -X
```

I get the following error (in the sonar-project.properties file the settings are the same as in the arguments I run sonar with).

```
20:37:07.492 INFO: Scanner configuration file: c:\tools\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
20:37:07.496 INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\users\Admin\desktop\mean-darts-app\sonar-project.properties
20:37:07.510 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
20:37:07.511 INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
20:37:07.511 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
20:37:07.601 DEBUG: keyStore is :
20:37:07.601 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
20:37:07.601 DEBUG: keyStore provider is :
20:37:07.602 DEBUG: init keystore
20:37:07.602 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
20:37:07.675 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\Admin\.sonar\cache
20:37:07.675 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
20:37:07.679 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
20:37:07.679 DEBUG: Download: https://sonarcloud.io/batch/index
20:37:08.465 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
20:37:08.467 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
20:37:08.488 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
20:37:08.498 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
20:37:08.499 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
20:37:08.504 DEBUG: Execution start
20:37:08.639 DEBUG: Publish global mode
20:37:08.717 INFO: Load global settings
20:37:09.435 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=713ms
20:37:09.472 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=756ms
20:37:09.483 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\Admin\.sonar\cache
20:37:09.636 INFO: Load plugins index
20:37:09.764 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/deploy/plugins/index.txt | time=128ms
20:37:09.770 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=134ms
20:37:09.773 DEBUG: Load plugins
20:37:09.910 DEBUG: Load plugins (done) | time=137ms
20:37:09.918 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin CVS [scmcvs] (built with API lower than 5.2)
20:37:09.919 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin SVN [scmsvn] (built with API lower than 5.2)
20:37:09.923 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Mercurial [scmmercurial] (built with API lower than 5.2)
20:37:09.924 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Google Analytics [googleanalytics] (built with API lower than 5.2)
20:37:09.925 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Git [scmgit] (built with API lower than 5.2)
20:37:10.084 DEBUG: Plugins:
20:37:10.085 DEBUG:   * CVS 1.0 (scmcvs)
20:37:10.085 DEBUG:   * SVN 1.3 (scmsvn)
20:37:10.085 DEBUG:   * SonarPLSQL 2.9.0.901 (plsql)
20:37:10.085 DEBUG:   * Fake Billing 1.0.2017.05.16 (billing)
20:37:10.086 DEBUG:   * C# 5.11.0.1761 (csharp)
20:37:10.086 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 4.10.0.10260 (java)
20:37:10.086 DEBUG:   * Web 2.5.0.476 (web)
20:37:10.086 DEBUG:   * Flex 2.3 (flex)
20:37:10.087 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.4.2.885 (xml)
20:37:10.087 DEBUG:   * VB.NET 3.0.3.346 (vbnet)
20:37:10.088 DEBUG:   * Swift 2.0.0.1127 (swift)
20:37:10.088 DEBUG:   * GitHub 1.4.1.822 (github)
20:37:10.089 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.8.0.1496 (python)
20:37:10.089 DEBUG:   * SonarCFamily 4.9.0.8153 (cpp)
20:37:10.090 DEBUG:   * GitHub Authentication for SonarQube 1.3 (authgithub)
20:37:10.090 DEBUG:   * SonarRPG 2.1.0.736 (rpg)
20:37:10.091 DEBUG:   * Mercurial 1.1.1 (scmmercurial)
20:37:10.091 DEBUG:   * Google Analytics 1.1 (googleanalytics)
20:37:10.092 DEBUG:   * SonarPLI 1.5.0.702 (pli)
20:37:10.092 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 3.0.0.4962 (javascript)
20:37:10.094 DEBUG:   * SonarCOBOL 3.4.0.1932 (cobol)
20:37:10.094 DEBUG:   * Git 1.2 (scmgit)
20:37:10.095 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.10.0.2087 (php)
20:37:10.096 DEBUG:   * ABAP 3.3 (abap)
20:37:10.096 DEBUG:   * SVG Badges 3.0.1 (status)
20:37:10.112 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
20:37:10.113 INFO: SonarQube server 6.4.0
20:37:10.113 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1250" (analysis is platform dependent)
20:37:10.114 DEBUG: Work directory: C:\users\Admin\desktop\mean-darts-app\.scannerwork
20:37:10.115 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
20:37:10.115 DEBUG: Execution execute
20:37:10.497 INFO: Process project properties
20:37:10.501 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:37:10.502 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
20:37:10.502 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:37:10.503 INFO: Total time: 3.027s
20:37:10.550 INFO: Final Memory: 59M/302M
20:37:10.550 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:37:10.551 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
```

Comment: if there is an alternative SA tool for angular, please let me know